# About apache Ignite service Implementation

Tags: java, ignite

If I have an interface

```
public interface TestService {
    public String getSomething();
}
```

and a class

```
import org.apache.ignite.services.Service;
import org.apache.ignite.services.ServiceContext;

public class TestServiceImpl implements Service, TestService {
    @Override
    public void init(ServiceContext ctx) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(ServiceContext ctx) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel(ServiceContext ctx) {
    }

    @Override
    public String getSomething() {
        return "HelloWorld";
    }
}
```

I deploy this service on ignite server nodes with

```
// Deploy services only on server nodes.
IgniteServices serverSvcs = ignite.services(ignite.cluster().forServers());

// Deploy cluster singleton.
serverSvcs.deployClusterSingleton("TestService", new TestServiceImpl());
```

And Ignite client node try to get the service

```
TestService testSvc = mIgnite.services().serviceProxy("TestService", TestService.class, false);
```

If the client node doesn't contain the "TestServiceImpl" class,

will catch exception with message:
"Failed to find class with given class loader for unmarshalling (make sure same versions of all classes are available on all nodes or enable peer-class-loading)",

Is it necessary that ignite client node must have the class TestServiceImpl ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed already and the fix will be released in upcoming Ignite 1.6. In the meantime you can download the nightly build and check if it works for you: http://ignite.apache.org/community/contribute.html#nightly-builds

Comment: When will it be released to Maven Central Repository?

Comment: I have seen a similar issue with 1.7. My Ignite cluster uses services that are not in the classpath of client nodes. I have seen the client nodes try to run those services, and fail with ClassNotFoundException.